# VSCode applying annoying red styling when using JS "?" operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

[image]

My VSCODE editor applies this red styling every time I use a JS '?' operator within JSX as seen on line 2. This makes it quite difficult to work and is really annoying, to be honest. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Doesn't look like a feature to be disabled. Do you have the right file type association in place? Maybe the editor thinks its looking at a plain HTML file.

Comment: @isherwood perhaps not. What would be the way to check this? Change language mode when set to JS or JSX does not fix the highlighting

Comment: Do you use eslint for validation? Normally this is an error that can happen is ether eslint, or eslints babel config, is wrong or dont allow modern . Eslint then dont know how to handle optional chaining

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of the Babel ES6/ES7 extension.